# react-native-plaid-link-sdk's redirect uri has access denied error with ios

Tags: ios, react-native, plaid

I have valid universal link for ios's deep linking. The universal link is used as redirect_uri of plaid client in react-native app. When I open the universal link in safari, it opens the correct content in the app. However, it causes "AccessDenied" exception with Plaid SDK. Anyone can help me resolve the issue?

- react-native-plaid-link-sdk@5.0.2
- react-native@0.61.5
- react-navigation(for deep linking)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the redirect URI on the [Plaid Dashboard](https://dashboard.plaid.com/team/api)?  It sounds like that might be the issue.

If you have and still can't get it working, definitely try opening a support ticket...